# Object Undefined Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have asked a question simpler to this before but I have made progress now.

I have a menu bar which uses 2 files of Javascript and then another 2 files of Javascript for another object on the page.

This is my code this is breaking at the moment:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Javascript/MenuBarAdmin/AdminMenuJS.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="Javascript/MenuBarAdmin/AdminMenuJSmin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Javascript/bSimplexMenuBarTransit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Javascript/bSimplexMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="Stylesheet/bSimplexMenuBar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Stylesheet/bPersonnelTracker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Stylesheet/ScheduleStyle/bsimplex.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      javascript: window.history.forward(1);
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      function select(e) {
          e.eventSelect(e);
          menu.show(e);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="script1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="bsimplex-header-bar">
          <ul class="modern-menu theme2">
            <li><a href="../../Common/bWelcomePage.aspx"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="../bPersonnelDashboardPage.aspx"><span>My Calender</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="../Manager/bManagerPage.aspx"><span>Manager</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span style="background-color: #f08100 !important;">Absences</span></a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="bSicknessPage.aspx"><span>Sickness</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="bMedicalPage.aspx"><span>Medical</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="bLatenessPage.aspx"><span>Lateness</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="bOtherPage.aspx"><span>Other</span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Reports</span></a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Allocation</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Rota</span></a><</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../Admin/bAdminPage.aspx"><span>Admin</span></a></li>
            <ul class="mm-group mm-right">
              <li class="mm-icon">
                <div class="menubaricon">
                  <img src="../../Images/bSimplex_icon_menubar.png" />
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">$(".modern-menu").modernMenu();</script>
     </div>
```

**The error comes at the bottom of the code when I am trying to find .modernMenu it just says that the object is undefined.**

The first 2 script lines that call javascript files are used for a vertical menu bar, and the second 2 are for the horizontal menu bar that isnt working.
.
I have ran through my code 100's of times to find the issue and when i comment out the first 2 lines for the vertical bar the error will go and will work correctly but the vertical bar wont work and visa versa.

**I dont know if im correct but at the bottom where the error is happening do i have to call the script file i want to get the information from? or am i limited to the amount of javascript files?**

Comment: Can you log `$(".modern-menu")` and see what outputs? Also, I'm pretty sure there's no "limit" to the number of JavaScript files you can link, but a lot of linked JavaScript files might the loading of the page. Also, it might be that the vertical bar scripts are messing with `$()`. Can you link us to where these scripts are coming from?

Comment: @NobleMushtak What you mean by log? and these scripts are in my project? i dont really want to be posting 100's of lines unless there is an easier way? I think they could be messing with $()

Comment: Call `console.log($(".modern-menu"));`.

Comment: You need to wrap jQuery (such as `$('selector')`) in either `$(document).ready(function() { /* code goes here */ });` or `$(function() { /*code*/ });`

Comment: @NobleMushtak On Command Window ? Or Immediate Window?

Comment: @Jason He's calling the `$()` at the end of the body, so it doesn't matter. Call it in place of `$(".modern-menu").modernMenu();` in your last `<script>` tag.

Comment: @NobleMushtak I honestly think its something to do with $() and the other styles messing it up. What code should I try?

Comment: Well, if the scripts are messing with `$()` so that you can't use it the same way, try using `jQuery()`.

Comment: @NobleMushtak How would I do that?

Comment: `jQuery()` is exactly the same as `$()`. Just replace `$` with `jQuery`.

Comment: @NobleMushtak OMG that actually worked, why did that work I dont understand? Please answer the question and i can vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script tags you're commenting out must be altering `$()` for their own purposes. There are actually many libraries that use the `$()` library, so jQuery has conveniently given a `jQuery()` function which is *exactly* the same as `$()`, but has a different name that's probably not going to be used by other libraries. Because the library you inserted altered `$()` so that it's not `jQuery()` anymore, use `jQuery()` instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(".modern-menu").modernMenu();</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(function(){
$(".modern-menu").modernMenu();
})
```

Comment: is there a way to try your code on jsfiddle? maybe its a problem with your js files

Comment: You need to add your JS files into your fiddle.